# Extracting a text from very large wav file using speech recognition

Tags: python-3.x, speech-recognition

I am having very large wav file ( approx 1 hour audio approx 700 mb) and I want to extract text from this file using python

my code is

```
from datetime import datetime
start_time = datetime.now()
print("Start Time : " + str(start_time))

import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.AudioFile("audio_chunk_1.wav") as source:
    audio = r.record(source)
try:
    s = r.recognize_google(audio)
    print("Text: "+s)
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception: "+str(e))

end_time = datetime.now()
print("End Time : " + str(end_time))
print('Duration: {}'.format(end_time - start_time))
```

it was giving me an error on my laptop so decided to split files

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

audio_file= "demo.wav"
audio = AudioSegment.from_wav(audio_file)

audio_chunk=audio[0:300000]
audio_chunk.export( "audio_chunk_{}.wav".format(1), format="wav")

audio_chunk=audio[300001:400000]
audio_chunk.export( "audio_chunk_{}.wav".format(2), format="wav")

audio_chunk=audio[400001:500000]
audio_chunk.export( "audio_chunk_{}.wav".format(3), format="wav")
```

I have to split wav files randomly to extract text. Can you pl suggest a better way to do it ?

Thanks